# Migrating to Android Studio with errors

Tags: android, eclipse, migration

I have problem with Android Studio. After I heard that in near future google will end support for Eclipse i decided to migrate to Android Studio, after I had done it, i imported my Eclipse's project and I get errors which I don't understand:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is my Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "morisson.rzucpalenie"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are building with buildTools 23.0.2 but your compileSdkVersion is 22. The compileSdkVersion should be 23 and your targetSdkVersion should be 23.

Comment: I changed it but  then i get error with compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

Comment: You need to change those to use the 23 versions too, so 23.1.1